# CSS immediate child selector

Tags: css

```
#main .container > div:not(.sites):not(.default) {
     display: none;
}
```

The `<h1>` tag is visible while the below `yui-ge` div tag is hidden.  If > only applies to immediate children how come my `yui-ge` is having the above CSS applied to it (both in Chrome and Firefox).

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='default selected'>
       <h1>Page Title</h1>
       <div class='yui-ge'> //for some reason, this tag remains hidden cause of the above CSS
          //more div tags
       </div>
    </div>
    //more HTML here
</div>
```

**update**

Look here: --LINK REMOVED--

Click the "Woot" tab.... no results are shown on the default woot tab - they remain hidden.

Comment: Maybe you should post a larger example and explain what exactly IS happening and what you think SHOULD happen.

Comment: Is the `h1` visible? I believe it might be that the css rule matches the `div` with class "default selected" by the "selected" class and therefore hides your div with class "yui-ge", but it would then also hide the `h1`. So is the `h1` still visible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have this CSS rule:

```
#main .woot > div:not(.sites):not(.default) {
    display: none;
}
```

This rule applies to all DIVs inside the `#main` element, that do not have the classes `sites` or `default` and are children of a `.woot` element.

Your structure is:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="woot">
        <div class="woot default selected">
            <div class="yui-ge"> ... </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `.yui-ge` DIV does not have the class `sites` nor `default` and it is inside a `.woot` element. Therefore, it will be hidden.

---

The problem is that you have two DIVs in the ancestor chain that have the class `woot`.

Comment: But it *looks* hidden when it has no content. ;)

Comment: @Golez :) However, it actually has content even in OP's code sample. The `//for some reason, ...` is regular text content.

Comment: That's true. I assumed that was just for illustrating the question.. :-/

Comment: Please look at the example I've provided in the original post

Answer (score 0):

If you hide an element, all it's child elements get hidden too.